# How to find the minimum index?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have vector `a=[7;4;3;2;5;6;2]` of length 7 and the element 2 is the minimum element, but there are two locations of where the minimum is.

I need to find the **smallest** position of the minimum element.  How can this be done in MATLAB?

Comment: Sort the whole vector, and loop till the length of the array divided by 2, and choose that element it will be the smallest value

Comment: Please explain the question better. I don't understand

Comment: I need direct command give me the index 4

Comment: assume vector a indexing from i=1 to 7

Comment: This question has been asked to death.  Look at the duplicate.

Comment: DIFFER.the duplicate is in my vector not in the Q?. be quiet and help me

Comment: i edit my ques again...pls help

Comment: Do you want to find ALL positions of where the minimum is?

Comment: no , i need just the minimum position

Comment: There's more than one 2. Do you want the first or last occurring? You're not making yourself clear.

Comment: 2 is in two positions. i need minimum position(which is 4)

Comment: @osman - Try my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second output of [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html).  It gives you the location of where the minimum was found.  In the case of there being more than one element being the minimum, the location returned is the first one found, corresponding to the **smallest** location:

```
>> a=[7;4;3;2;5;6;2];
>> [~,ind] = min(a);
>> ind

ind =

     4
```